# Button Background Image using behind code Button.Style.Add()

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Quick question. I am dynamically creating some buttons and basically want to add a background image to them in the code behind. Can someone tell me how its supposed to look like? I want to use the Button.Style.Add().

I tried Button.Style.Add("background-image","url(~/Uploads/Steak.jpg)"); but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string strimgpath = "Uploads/Steak.jpg";
String strImgLocation = "url('" + strimgpath + "')";
idimage.Style.Add("background-image", strImgLocation);
```

Comment: Thank you, I found the answer before your post but yours is exactly correct. The "~/" that I added was making the problem. I have done it as you have written it and it is working without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

please use following code:

```
Button.Style.Add("background-image","url('~/Uploads/Steak.jpg')");
```

Add single quotes to the url

Comment: I had tried this previously, tried it again, just as you wrote it and my button is still with its default appearance.

Comment: Try using- Button.Attributes.Add("style", "background-image:url('~/Uploads/Steak.jpg');");